# My dynamically allocated 2d array print random gibberish with no meaning

Tags: c

This code can get the first row to print, but for some reason will not get the first column to print. If this clarifies the question a bit the x values print but the y value barely does, I get some weird characters instead.

```
char** GenerateLand(int width, int height) {
    char** GenLand;
    int i;
    
    GenLand = malloc(width * sizeof(char*));
    
    for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        GenLand[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * height);
    }
    
    char RandChar = PickLandType();
    

    int x, y;
    
    for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        if(x == 0) {
            GenLand[x][0] = RandChar; 
        } else {
            char RandChar1 = GenerateNeighbor(RandChar);
            GenLand[x-1][0] = GenerateNeighbor(RandChar1);
           for( y = 0; y < height ; y++){
                if(y == 0){
                GenLand[x][y] = RandChar;
            } else {
            char RandChar2 = GenerateNeighbor(RandChar);
            GenLand[0][y-1] = GenerateNeighbor(RandChar2);
        }
     }
   }    

    return GenLand;
    
    for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        free(GenLand[i]);
    }
    free(GenLand);
}

char GenerateNeighbor(char item)
{
 switch(item)
 {
    case 'R':
        return NewFromRuralLand();
        break;
    case 'F':
        return NewFromForest();
        break;
    case 'T':
        return NewFromTown();   
        break;
    case 'W':
        return NewFromWater();
        break;
    case 'C':
        return NewFromCity();
        break;
    case 'M':   
        return NewFromMountain();
        break;  
    default:
        printf("Error!");   
        break;
  }
}


char PickLandType()
{
 int typeOfLand = rand()%5;   
 if(typeOfLand == 0){
    return 'R';
 } else if(typeOfLand == 1){
    return 'F';
 } else if(typeOfLand == 2){
    return 'T';
 } else if(typeOfLand == 3){
    return 'W';
 } else if(typeOfLand == 4){
    return 'C';
 } else if(typeOfLand == 5){
    return 'M';
 }
}

void PrintLand(char** Land, int width, int height) {
    int x, y;
    for( x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for( y = 1; y < height ; y++){
            printf("%c", Land[x][y]);           
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Fec.png ^ Picture of error, was hoping someone could tell me why I keep getting these cryptic unreadable values. Sorry I don't have enough reputation points to directly embed the picture. I checked my NewFrom() functions and they all work so I do not believe they are the issue. The output is supposed to be organized by row and column:

Comment: This exact same question, with only the code less formatted and readable, was posted a couple of hours ago. If that was you then please don't to that, edit your question to improve it instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: And this code might have solved one problem (besides the readability issue from the previous question), but many others still remain.

Comment: Look at the indexing you use. That should explain what is being done. Hint: when do you write to any other column than 0 in any other than the first row? And there’s even undefined behavior.

Comment: Did you know that `return` stops the function and doesn't run the code after it?

Comment: At he end of `GenerateLand` you free the array. However, that part is never reached because you `return` before it, which is good, because it seems you want to _return_ the array and not free it. So remove that code (or move it to a `freeLand` function).

Comment: The statement `GenLand[0][y-1] = ...` is a bit strange. Probably `[0]` should be `[x]` and `[y-1]` is undefined for `y==0`. So check how and why you are indexing what.

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Comment: I added edited the code a bit, and I can get part of the array to print however I am still having an issue with the cryptic lettering. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas? And to answer previous questions I am intending to only print in the  0th row and 0th column for now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, hence I have to write this as an answer.

1. Your freeing code at the end of GenerateLand will never run, there is an unconditional return statement prior to it. (NB: You shouldn't be freeing it regardless as you want to return `GenLand`, just remove the `free`ing code)
2. Without giving us the `PickLandType` and `GenerateNeighbor` functions, we can't tell you why your code returns a garbled mess of letters. Please edit and attach these functions.
3. This is the exact same question you asked before, except now you've attached different output - have you changed the code inbetween? If so, please attach the updated code.
4. This is bad code, the first iteration will access `GenLand[0][-1]`:

```
            for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                GenLand[0][y-1] = GenerateNeighbor(RandChar1);
            }
```

5. Please try and keep your code nicely formatted to that it's easier for everyone to read.

If you want an answer that can actually help, give the `GenerateNeighbor` and `PickLandType` functions, and also give us an expected output.

Edit:

6. As Paul Ogilvie pointed out, the code in point 4 will also only ever generate the 0th column (the left most column). You probably meant for this to be `GenLand[x][y]` (but once again, see point 4)